# Practice for returning a value or equivalent variable?

Tags: programming-practices, coding-style, coding-standards

I think it would be easiest to explain what I'm asking with an example.

```
function getLastNode() {

    let current = this.head;

    if (current == null) {
        // Here, we could either return current, or return null
    }

    while (current.getNext() != null) {
        current = current.getNext();
    }

    return current;
}
```

---

In the beginning of the function, in the if statement, we have a choice to either write the return statement as `return current` or `return null`. In situations like this you could choose either option since they are equivalent.

To avoid this question being considered primarily opinion-based, I want to know if there is any type of convention for this. Is there a standard, convention, or style guide that specifies a standard practice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two things to always consider:

1. Consider which leaves your code most responsive to change
2. Consider which is easier to read

1 might argue for current if the flag value might ever be something other than null, I don't see that happening myself.

2 argues for null because it says flat out: if you're here, you're returning null.  Even makes life in the debugger easier.

On balance, I'll take `return null` here.

<sub>The views presented here should in no way be construed as an endorsement of [null](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=null%20the%20billion%20dollar%20mistake).</sub>

Comment: I'd also side with (2) .. to me, the test is to detect a "(somewhat) abnormal state" and the result in such cases should be `null`. The fact that `current` _happens_ to be `null` in the current test is (almost) accidental, and so should not be relied on.  (A future "abnormal state" test might be `if( current == null || current.isInvalid() ) return null`)

Comment: @TripeHound a very good point. That's actually a point in favor of being responsive to change.

Comment: @CandiedOrange Yes, I'm coming from a "responsive to change" P.O.V.; I probably should have said "I also side with `return null`" -- the (2) in my original comment was referring to the "_2 argues for null..." part, rather than the "2...easier to read" part.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of having a separate `return` for the empty list, I'd just put the `while` loop into an `if(current != null) {` block and then return `current` unconditionally.

It's not always necessary to avoid multiple `return`s in a method, but if it's possible and even makes the code more succinct, you should do it.

Comment: Avoid multiple returns when your resources don't throw exceptions (say in c).  Otherwise beware of heading down the path to the [arrow anti pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrowAntiPattern).

Comment: If you "just put the `while` loop into an `if(current != null) {` block", you now have an extra level of nesting. Not saying you are wrong. but I'd argue that returning early is better practice than creating extra layers of nesting.